# Forming hypothesis based on difference in difference test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial, difference-in-difference

I am trying to rewrite my hypothesis for my study which uses a difference in difference type design. 
My study is concerned with the causal effect of development aid on support for democracy in a local community. I theorize that receiving development aid will have a positive impact on local support for democracy. In order to test this theory I match spatial data on the location of aid projects to survey data on local citizens' support for democracy.

Aid is not randomly allocated and in order to account for the potential selection effects of aid targeting, as well as pre-correlated levels of local support for democracy, I use a difference in difference type design where I compare differences between three groups (a group that presently receives aid, a group that will receive aid and a group that does not receive aid) in order to isolate the causal effect of aid from potential selection effects.

My hypothesis then:

*Citizens in areas where aid projects are active will have greater levels of support for democracy than citizens in areas where aid projects will be implemented in the future but are not currently active.*

I cannot find any examples of studies which state a falsifiable hypothesis and use a difference in difference design and so I am concerned whether I am structuring my hypothesis correctly.

Should I also make reference to my control category ie. citizens who are not exposed to aid ?

Perhaps something like: *hypothesis is based on comparisons to a control group in which citizens are not exposed to aid

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, aid is not randomly allocated, but it is credible that the timing of aid is as random. Moreover, you can dismiss strong anticipation effect. 
Hence, you want to compare the aided-groups to the later-aided-group in a diff-in-diff setting.

Your hypothesis is: *Citizens in areas where aid projects are active will have greater levels of support for democracy.*

The way you test your hypothesis is to consider as a control group the group of those that will have aid projects later. (you may dispell the never-aided group and no longer make reference to them.)

In case you cannot dismiss anticipation effects however, I suggest your hypothesis remains: *Citizens in areas where aid projects are active will have greater levels of support for democracy than citizens in areas where aid projects will be implemented in the future but are not currently active.*

Comment: Does this help ? To be honnest, I was not sure to well understand the sentence: *I cannot find any examples of studies which state a falsifiable hypothesis and use a difference in difference design*